About the notion of invertibility in non unitary rings (or semigroups).
Sorry if this one was already asked, I did not find it. Here is the story:
Let us take a unitary ring $R$, the notion of unit element is very clear:
$$r \in R^{\times} \iff \exists r' \in R \mid rr' = 1 = r'r$$
Of course one can lighten this statement with only left or right invertibility in the finite case (due to the finiteness of endomorphism rings).
For finite unitary rings we also have the result $\forall r \in R$, $r$ is either a unit or a divisor (left and right) of zero.
This can be achieved by studying the ring morphisms:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
R & \to & \mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{Mod}-R} (R_R) \\
r & \mapsto & (\tau_r: s \mapsto rs)
\end{array}$$
Being a unit is then equivalent for $\tau_r$ to be an automorphism an a zero divisor
Now when we study these same ring morphism (that become rng morphisms) when $R$ is non-unitary, we also have the result if $R$ is finite: either $R$ is unitary or $R$ has only  zero divisors.
This can be proven since we have an equivalence: $i\in R$ is a unit for $R$ $\iff$ $\tau_i$ is the identity. But I can prove it only when $R$ is finite.
My 2 (very) related questions:

Q1 (answered): **Are there examples of (infinite) non unitary rings which have a unit on the left but not on the right? **(i.e. $\tau_r = \mathrm{id}_{R_R}$ but $(\tau'_r :s \mapsto rs) \neq \mathrm{id}_{{}_R\! R}$).
And as @rschwieb stated if we have both left and right units, they are the same.
Thanks to @IzaakvanDongen, we have the answer, there are examples of such right but not left identity and we can have multiple left (or right) identities.
My main motivation is to find a somewhat "canonical" isomorphism from the following morphism:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\hom_{\mathrm{Mod}-R}(R_R ,X_R)& \to& X_R \\
f & \mapsto & f(i)
\end{array}$$
Which would then be bijective.

Q2: Wether or not we have these left or right unit, if the have a rng $R$, if we have left or right invertible elements (with this following definition):

Def: $r\in R$ is quasi left (resp. right) invertible on the left if $\tau_r$ is a monomorphism (resp. epimorphism) and left (resp. right) invertible on the left if $\tau_r$ is a split monomorphism (resp. epimorphism).

Of course if there is a retraction (or section) of the form $\tau_{r'}$ split (or epi) this definition is equivalent to have $r'$ such that $r'r = i$ where $i$ is the unit on the left (so it has to exist). But since it is not necessarily the case, do we have example of such modules with left (quasi)-invertible elements on the left?
Some motivation for this definition:
For the previous "altered morphism" $f \in \hom(R_R,X_R) \mapsto f(r)\in X$ we would have $r$ quasi right invertible on the left $\implies$ this morphism is injective, since knowing $f(r)$ implies knowing $f\circ \tau_r$.
Furthermore if it is right invertible on the left ($\tau_r$ split epi with section $s \in \mathrm{End}(R_R)$) the association, $x \mapsto (t \in R \mapsto x \cdot s(t))$ is an right inverse map of our injective ring morphism.
I would like to say it is an iso but this problem looks a lot like studying the representable functors:
Here our "representables" would be the morphisms $x^\wedge : R_R \to X$ that send $r$ on $x \cdot r$, the problem is how can we retrieve $x$ from this? This situation is not likely to have a solution without a proper unit on the left.
Now if $r$ is left invertible on the left, $\tau_r$ has a retraction $\mu$ one should have surjectivity on our iso?

So don't hesitate to correct me if I'm wrong, but given a quasi-right inverse on the left $r$, we have an injective ring morphism:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\hom_{\mathrm{Mod}-R}(R_R ,X_R)& \to& X_R \\
f & \mapsto & f(r)
\end{array}$$
Furthermore if this quasi-right inverse on the left is a right inverse on the left, this is an isomorphism of rings with inverse:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
X_R& \to& \hom_{\mathrm{Mod}-R}(R_R ,X_R) \\
x & \mapsto & (t \mapsto x \cdot s(r))
\end{array}$$
where $s$ is a section of the split epimorphism $\tau_r$.

PS: These two questions have motivated this present question:

If R is a finite ring without unity, then every element of R must be zero divisor?
Trouble understanding tensor product of Hom set and module


"do we have example of such modules with left quasi-invertible elements on the left?" do you mean to ask if there are examples of such rings with left-quasi-invertible elements? Isn't that the same thing as asking for right regular elements, like $2\in\mathbb Z$? I feel like I don't understand what's being asked there.

@rschwieb I made a typo what I was interested in is when $\tau_r$ is an epi, but not split (and for non unitary rings). Also I’m still interested in cases where we only have unit on the left.

I made some corrections here $2$ would not work, even for the non-unital ring $2\mathbb{Z}$. I need the converse (multiplication by $r$ is surjective)

Here is the standard example of a ring with identity on one side but not the other. I'm not sure I follow your remark "Of course in this case, the left or right unit is unique since..." - this is in fact never the case, if I understand you correctly. Particularly I don't understand how you got $ii' = i'i$.

@IzaakvanDongen I made a mistake composing $\tau_i$ and $\tau_{i’}$ and assuming $r \mapsto \tau_r$ is injective (which is dumb) thanks for the link
